# htaccess redirect without losing url

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I want my website to redirect from https://www.sitename.com/single-product/supplier-name/supplier-id/article-name/article-id to https://www.sitename.com/single-product and want the same original URL restored.

Currently, https://www.sitename.com/single-product/supplier-name/supplier-id/article-name/article-id URL gets me to 404

I know I will have to use the P flag in .htaccess file in document root to get this working. But I don't know why my solution is not working

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/single-product
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /single-product/$1 [P]`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution not it is not working on my server. I guess mod_proxy is currently off on my server

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule single-product/* https://www.sitename.com/single-product/ [P]`

This is a great website to test these scripts
https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/